# How to make a button on a application open a register page in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0

I'm making an application group chat in Visual Studio learn a bit more, all is good so far, so I've made my design and coded most of what I need, I have added a Button and called it Register now what I want is when people click it it will open another page or some type of menu where people can type there information in to register, I thought somthing like this or is this so wrong.

```
    private void RegisterButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     //what gose here   
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Response.Redirect inside the button click to do this.

Refer to these articles:-
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx
https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/kb/307903